# Modx: Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to modParser::collectElementTags() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: php, plugins, compiler-errors, modx

Just started with new project and want to try ModX to use it for the project but get stuck on this error (it won't disappear) :

```
**Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to modParser::collectElementTags() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\Personal\illumation\modx\core\model\modx\modstaticresource.class.php on line 57 and defined in D:\Personal\illumation\modx\core\model\modx\modparser.class.php on line 101**
```

It went wrong at the moment I want to try to write a plugin so i created a new plugin in the Manager in an external file called `webit-core-plugin.php`. Add one event to it and save it. After this, the error described above appear.

Tried to remove it, do it again etc, nothing helps. Does anybody know what is going on?

I use the latest XAMPP, latest SQL/PHP and lastest ModX running on localhost (windows 7) with adminstrator privileges.

Comment: Check your static file path has been set up correctly. Did you select a valid Media Source and is the file path correct? Try selecting the Media Source again and re-saving.

Comment: Also - uncheck 'Is Static', then copy and paste your plugin code into the 'plugin code' field. If it works, you'll know for sure the problem is something to do with the Static File functionality (and not your plugin code).

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear Cache folder manually by deleting it through file browser
2. Open your SQL client, check your elements (templates - *modx_site_templates*, chunks - *modx_site_htmlsnippets*, snippets - *modx_site_snippets*, and plugins - *modx_site_plugins*) that have "static" field = 1, but have "static_file" empty.